# COMException using WebBrowser control in certain 2008 R2 Environments

Tags: c#, com, webbrowser-control, comexception, hresult

In certain 2008 R2 environments and not others, I'm getting a `COMExceptions` when utilizing a `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` control. Whether specifying contents via the `DocumentText` property or invoking the `Navigate` method with a URL parameter, I get the same exception:

**COMException - Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.**

at `System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IWebBrowser2.Refresh()`

I've found that setting the `ScrollBarsEnabled` property on the `WebBrowser` before specifying `DocumentText` causes this exception, and that appears to be as a result of calling the `Refresh` method (referenced above) when the browser has no contents (Last post [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/csharpgeneral/thread/71282b3d-c6f4-4850-853e-d56ff47a5d24)). A workaround for this is to set some mock contents and calling `Application.DoEvents()`. But even with this in place, it causes the above exception while loading the contents later on (done in another thread).

Note that the `DocumentCompleted` delegate I specify **is** being hit, but its `WebBrowser.axIWebBrowser2.StatusText` shows that the exception has occurred, and the `WebBrowser.Document` is empty.

I could put up a simple app to repro the issue, but I'd have to find a 2008 R2 instance where the bug is reproducible in order to debug. I'm more asking if anyone has ideas of what might be affecting or causing the issue, perhaps with relation to COM security etc.

Note that I am executing the `WebBrowser` in a `STA Apartment` state.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
-Max